# How can I exclude my count from my grade average?

Tags: python, count

I'm trying to figure out how to have a count when when I want to display my file, but not have the count get added into my grade average.

```
def main():
    choice = "q"
    while choice != "X":
        print_menu()
        choice = input("Enter an option (D, C, X): ")
        if choice == "D":
            DisplayScores()
        elif choice == "C":
            CalcAverage()

def print_menu():
    print("D. Display Grades")
    print("C. Calculate Average")
    print("X. Exit Application")

def DisplayScores():
    try:
        infile = open("data.txt",'r')
        count = 0
        for line in infile:
            count += 1
            print(count,line.rstrip("\n"))
            line = infile.readline() 
        infile.close()
    except IOError:
        print("File does not exist.")
    except:
        print("Unknown error.")

def CalcAverage():
    Average = 0.0
    try:
        datafile = open("data.txt", 'r')
        for grade in datafile:
            total = float(grade)
            Average += total
            print("The average of the class is: ", format(Average/29, '.2f'))
    except IOError:
        print("Something is wrong with the file.")
        print("Unknown Error.")
    datafile.close()

main()
```

Comment: What format is the data from the text file in?

Comment: Welcome to SO, I'm seeing the question as very valid in nature, but please show us what `data.txt` contains or at least a sample of.. This way it's easier to formulate a response

Comment: _I'm trying to figure out how to have a count when when I want to display my file_ A count of what?

Comment: the file contains grades ranging from 62 to 100 EX:

65
78
76
99
87
etc.
in my program i need it to have a number before each grade as if it was a student

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you printing the average each time through the loop?  You can't know what the average is until the loop is finished.  Also, it would be better to divide by the actual number of grades in the file, instead of assuming 29.  Try this instead:

```
total = 0.0
grades = 0
try:
    datafile = open("data.txt", 'r')
    for grade in datafile:
        grades += 1
        total += float(grade)
    print("The average of the class is: ", format(total/grades, '.2f'))
```